# Change for loop result to reverse order in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this javascript  .

```
<html>
    <div>
        <li class="class0 class1" data-slide-to="0">Start</li>
     </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var i;
         for(i=0; i<3; i++){
             $(".class1").after("<li Class='class0' data-slide-to='"+i+"'>"+i+"</li>");
         }
      </script>  
</html>
```

And i get the out put as

```
Start
3
2
1
0
```

But i want to get this result in following order

```
start
0
1
2
3
```

how i get this ?How to revert the result?

Comment: That loop will output `0, 1, 2`

Comment: Select last element of `.class0` using`$(".class0:last").append('target html')`

Comment: to answer the question as specified "change for loop" ... `for(i=3; i>=0; i--){`

Comment: the use of the word "output" suggests you were talking about the "output" - nevermind, deleted my miscorrection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after) method it would append after the `li`. So get the parent and append the element. Although you need to update the condition in order to generate `4` elements and your HTML is not valid the `li` should be the child of `ul` or `ol`.

```html
<html>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="class0 class1" data-slide-to="0">Start</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $(".class1").parent().append("<li Class='class0' data-slide-to='" + i + "'>" + i + "</li>");
  }
</script>

</html>
```

---

Or geneate elements in reverse order.

```html
<html>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="class0 class1" data-slide-to="0">Start</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var i = 4;
  while (i--) {
    $(".class1").parent().append("<li Class='class0' data-slide-to='" + i + "'>" + i + "</li>");
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `<= 3` to get required output :p (or < 4 as you say :p )

Comment: could you please explain more about parent() .

Comment: @John : the parent() method would get the parent of the element... in my snippet it would select ul..... and append() method add content at the end of ul...

Answer (score 2):

Change your script to work the other way around. So start at 3, and stop when you're at 0:

```
 <script>
     var i;
     for(i=3; i>0; i--){
         $(".class1").after("<li Class='class0' data-slide-to='"+i+"'>"+i+"</li>");
     }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<div>
    <li class="class0 class1" data-slide-to="0">Start</li>
 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var i;
     for(i=3; i>=3; i--){
         $(".class1").after("<li Class='class0' data-slide-to='"+i+"'>"+i+"</li>");
     }
  </script>
```